# Getting name for True after running str.endswith("")

Tags: python, pandas

```
city_df["Geography"].str.endswith("Quebec")
```

This is my code which gives me list of True and False. I want get all the names of cities that are set to True.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select rows from a DataFrame based on values in a column in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-values-in-a-column-in-pandas)

Answer (score 1):

you are almost there.

```
mask = city_df["Geography"].str.endswith("Quebec")
quebec_city = city_df[mask]
```

provide a more complete example may be helpful.